# Varying button title color for dark interface in Xcode Builder for tvOS

Tags: xcode, tvos, ios-darkmode

I am trying to vary the button title color for a dark interface in tvOS dark mode with XCode interface builder but it applies for all modes as default UIButton title color. I clicked "vary for dark interface as usual", and then clicked on "done varying".

[xcode interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgzUA.jpg)

Why doesn't it work ?